# How to continue a stage in jenkins pipeline even if the build fails

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I have a pipeline with multiple stages and with each stage there are couple of build job processes.  When I run the pipeline and there is a failure in any one of the builds the stage fails and doesn't build the other builds in the stage.  How can I get around this so it builds the remaining jobs in the stage?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the convention

```
try {
    // your build steps
    } finally {
        // always run...
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work @AmitYogev
 `node('ssp') {
   parallel("stream 1" : {
  stage('build') { 
   for (item in build) {
    try{
     buildJob(item)
    }
    catch (e) {
     throw e
    }
            }
  }
   },
 
 "stream 2 (stream 2)" : {
  stage('test') {
   for (item in Tests) {
    try{
     buildJob(item)
    }
    catch (e) {
     throw e
    }
            }
  }
 }
)} `

Comment: the step stops because you throw the exception. try not throwing e and the next step will start